# Fill missing values (na) with an list/series after modelling missing values

Tags: python, list, pandas, missing-data, fillna

I am trying to plug the predicted missing values into original df (of course to the column with missing value). How could I do so?

The predicted missing values are basically stored in a list/series whose length is the number of missing values in the original df. The order in the list matches with the order that missing values appear in the df, I think, since I split the test_set from the df using nonull() at the missing series.

I have been trying `pd.Series.fillna`, but that just allows one value to replace.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely do so next times

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and pandas [isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) function to do that.

```
df['relevant_column'] = np.where(df['relevant_column'].isnull(),
                                 predicted_values,
                                 df['relevant_column'])
```

predicted_values should be a pandas series or 1d numpy array with the same lenght as the dataframe.